# Are any of these Soyuz controls involved in separating the orbital module?

Tags: spacecraft, soyuz-spacecraft, russia

[According to this Q & A](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/30369/195), it's very likely that the Soyuz spacecraft's orbital module can be manually separated independent of other spacecraft operations.

On [this CollectSpace page](http://www.collectspace.com/ubb/Forum14/HTML/001441.html), there's an excellent photo of a bank of Soyuz control panel buttons with guards to protect against accidental activation of critical functions:

[image: 4 by 4 array of buttons, each row with a common metal guard plate, lifted up in the picture. Each button is labeled in abbreviated Cyrillic text.]

I note that three of the buttons (#3, #12, #13) are labeled with "БO", the abbreviation for бытовой отсек (bytovoi otsek), or Orbital Module. I don't know any Russian, so I can't tell what the remainder of the labels say. It looks like buttons #12 and #13 are labeled very similarly if not identically.

**Are any of these labels plausibly interpretable as "separate/jettison/disconnect orbital module"?**

Any transliteration/translation/interpretation of the other controls  is welcome in addition.

Comment: *laughs* question initiated by desperate astronaut on ISS

Comment: Only one way to find out, press and see what happens.

Comment: @coredump: You really don't want to jettison the service module *before* you perform the reentry burn.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The 12th and 13th Critical Command Keys "ОТСТРЕЛ БО" are БО (Orbital Module) Jettison.

> The БО separation (jettison) can be executed either automatically on
> the nominal separation schedule within the unified cyclogram or on the
> ОВК12 and ОВК 13 Critical Commands in case of the urgent descent
> before the СКД (Orbital Maneuver Engine) ignition for retrofire.

Perhaps you have to press them both simo? (Still checking on that.)

Source: [Soyuz Crew Operations Manual](https://www.infosondas.com/2017/04/pdf-soyuz-crew-operations-manual-soycomrop-19final/).

This is all I can find from there on the Critical Command Keys.

[image]

1. Descent Flag
2. Separation Config (service module?)
3. ?
4. ?
5. ?
6. ?
7. Ignite
8. ?
9. Separation (service module?)
10. Contingency Power On
11. ?
12. Orbital Module Jettison
13. Orbital Module Jettison
14. ?
15. ?
16. Thermal Sensors Disconnect
17. Configur Depressurize (sic) Arm the depress system?
18. Depressurize

Comment: I wonder if any of the agencies considered pictographs/iconography for controls on international missions.

Comment: Yeah. The official language of the ISS is English.  But...

Comment: I'm having trouble finding a good gloss; Google translate gives ОТСТРЕЛ -> "dismissed" for uppercase and отстрел -> "shooting" for lowercase.

Comment: Good find, though!

Comment: The duplication of the OM jett control is really interesting -- is it really the most drastic of these operations, that it requires the extra guard of simultaneous press?

Comment: The depress has an arm/fire and is behind a screwed-down panel guard....maybe it's worse.

Comment: I suppose it's rather a redundant button, so that pressing one or the other would work. You do this after the reentry burn, not quite enough time to dismantle the panel and short the contacts if the button fails.

Comment: The document always refers to command 12 AND 13. But it's poorly written, there us not enough info for me to tell.

Answer (score 14):

1. Descent/discharge mark (flag, warning, attribute)
2. Preparation to separation
3. Open KSD (pressure relief valve) of BO (orbital module)
4. [explosive] separation of mechanical contacts
5. Choice of DPO-B (Primary Berthing and Attitude Control
   Thrusters) for descent
6. **emergency detachment**
7. SKD (Orbital Maneuver Engine) on
8. SKD (Orbital Maneuver Engine) off
9. Separation
10. Emergency supply on
11. Connection of pressurized sections
12. **(explosive) detachment of BO (orbital module)**
13. **(explosive) detachment of BO (orbital module)**
14. Conservation (Soyuz Crew Ops manual translates it literally as "Conservation, Pickling")
15. thermal sensor on-line
16. thermal sensor off-line
17. prepare dehermetization
18. dehermetization

Comment: Thanks for the translations -- unfortunately I can only accept one answer.